# Can't Ping device even though they are directly connected

Tags: networking

I have this configure in my computer `192.168.2.1/24` and this is the IP configured in device `192.168.2.63/24` the device was directly connected to my computer. it is not connected to any router. It's a Biometric device from zkteco and it is directly connected into my PC via Ethernet.

Comment: Do you happen to know the exact model of your ZKTeco time clock? I want to check out the manual. Welcome to SU!

Comment: It's ZKTeco K30. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

I've set up one of those time clocks before.

The main difference for me was that I used a 5-port gigabit switch between the PC and the ZKTeco device, to ensure that the lack of crossover cable wouldn't be an issue.

- The first thing I suggest you try is the exact same thing you're doing now, except connecting the time clock and your PC to a switch or router, instead of directly into each other.
- There's a slim possibility that both your PC and the ZKTeco device don't have auto MDI-X support, and so can't communicate due to the fact you're using a regular Ethernet cable instead of a crossover cable.

Comment: I will try to change the cable from crossover then. but my configuration is good? they can see each other with that IP's ?

Comment: Your configuration looks okay. They're both on the same subnet. Try with a crossover cable if you have one, just to rule that out.